# Set checkbox is checked or not from json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, checkbox

I have checkbox and I want to change it's value using jquery depending on values come by json data
I restore string in database that determine the value of every html element 
like this

```
bandwidthcap:=false,download:=,upload:=,restrict:=true
```

the bandwidthcap is  toggle checkbox 
but the program every time set it as checked even if the value is false as you can see.
this is the jquery code to get json data and set it to html elements

```
 var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "Save.php?id=gettallemplate&tempname="+name,

      dataType: "json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
        //}
//alert(jsonData);
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
    var array = obj['data'].split(",");
    $.each(array,function(i){ var array2 = array[i].split(":=");

        $('#'+array2[0]).val(array2[1]);
        $('#'+array2[0]).attr('checked', array2[1]);

});
```

`array2[0]` contain the element ID and the `array2[1]` contain value 
for bandwidthcap checkbox 
`$('#bandwidthcap').attr('checked',false)`
but it give checked 
I searched alote without result

Comment: convert `.attr()` to `.prop()` and check. Make sure that  `array2[1]` has value `true` or `false`

Comment: I changed it before without result

Comment: I am sure that array2[1] has false value

Comment: do `console.log(array2[1]);` and see what is coming. Don't be sure without checking

Comment: You probably need to change your jsonData. `bandwidthcap`, `download`, `upload`, each of them should have `true` or `false`. Don't keep them empty. `download:=,upload:=` won't split as required bcz you haven't specified `true` or `false`.

Comment: I checked that the coming is false

Comment: so what's the issue? is it coming as checked even value is false?

Comment: I changed also without result and  I removed download and upload and just bandwidthcap:=false remain in the json data but every time it give checked

Comment: yes it coming checked even if it false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`true` and `false` are being treated as `string` and hence you can't use/treat them as boolean.

You need to check:

```
var flag = (array2[1] === "true");
```

And use `flag` to set checkbox as checked or unchecked:

```js
var someData = 'bandwidthcap:=false,download:=,upload:=,restrict:=true';
var array = someData.split(",");
$.each(array, function(i) {
  var array2 = array[i].split(":=");
  var flag = (array2[1] === "true");
  $('#' + array2[0]).val(array2[1]);
  $('#' + array2[0]).attr('checked', flag);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='bandwidthcap' />
<input type='checkbox' id='download' />
<input type='checkbox' id='upload' />
<input type='checkbox' id='restrict' />
```

Comment: @M.Bwe Glad to help you! Happy Coding! :)